# Find the general solution of the equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find the general solution of the equation $|\sin x| = \cos x$.

My Approach: $$|\sin x|  = \sqrt {(1-\sin^2x)} $$
$$\sin^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x$$
$$\sin^2 x = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sin^2 x = \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$x = n \pi \pm \frac {\pi}{4}$$

But my book has the general solution as $x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$
But I don't see any reason to reject one answer since the mod on $\sin x$ compensates for it.
Can anybody figure out where am I going wrong?

Comment: Wolfram alpha says that the general solution is $x=2n\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Very first step: $|\sin x|  = \sqrt {1-\sin^2x} $ means that $|\sin x|  = |\cos x| $, not that $|\sin x|  = \cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to realize that in order for $|\sin(x)|$ to equal $\cos(x)$, the angle must be in the first or fourth quadrants. Then, I would think of which unit circle points had the same $x$ and $y$ values:

[image]

It should be obvious from this picture and logic that the general answer is $x = \pm\frac\pi4+2\pi n$.

The singular error in your work is in your setup: $\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ is equal to $|\cos(x)|$. Thus, you have solved for all $x$ for which $|\sin(x)|=|\cos(x)|$. Fixing this error but still solving with a similar method is difficult.

Comment: Can you please help me identifying my mistake? Why am I getting $n\pi$ instead of $2n\pi$? If I go according to my book, It says that the general solution of $sin^2\theta = sin^2\alpha$ is $n\pi \pm \alpha$. But then according to you guys, The answer comes out to be $2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I have added an explanation of your error to my answer.

Comment: But since I squared on both the sides, the mod shouldn't really matter.

Comment: squaring both sides changes the equation: $x^2=y^2$ only implies that $|x|=|y|$, not that $x = y$ or $|x| = y$. The logic you are using is "if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x = y$", which leads to immediately false results such as "$0\cdot x = 0\cdot y$ implies $x=y$"

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem from the first line: $\cos x$ can be negative. Avoiding square roots, you can say that, generally speaking,
$$|A|=B\iff A^2=B^2\;\textbf{and}\; B\ge 0,$$
and in particular:
$$|\sin x|=\cos x\iff\sin^2x=\cos^2x \;\textbf{and}\;\cos x\ge 0. $$
Now use the linearisation formulæ:
 $$\sin^2x=\cos^2x\iff\frac{1-\cos 2x}2=\frac{1+\cos 2x}2\iff \cos 2x=0,$$
so the solutions of the *equation* are
$$2x\equiv \frac\pi2\mod \pi\iff x\equiv \frac\pi4\mod\frac\pi2.$$
Among these solutions, keep those for which $\cos x\ge 0$:
$$x\equiv \pm\frac\pi4\mod2\pi. $$

Answer (score 0):

squaring our equation we obtain $$\sin(x)^2=\cos(x)^2$$ and this can written as
$$(\sin(x)-\cos(x))(\sin(x)+\cos(x))=0$$
the solution is given by $$x_1=2\arctan(1-\sqrt{2})+2k\pi$$ or $$x_2=-2\arctan(1-\sqrt{2})+2k\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Neither your nor your book answer is correct. In fact, $|\sin(x)|=\cos(x) \implies \cos(x) \ge 0$. Consequently, $x$ should lie in the first or fourth quadrant.

First, $|\sin(x)|=\cos(x) \implies \sin(x)=\pm \cos(x) \implies \tan(x)=\pm 1 \implies x=  \pm \frac{\pi}{4}+k \pi$.
For odd $k$, $x$ lies in the second and third quadrants. Therefore, $\cos(x) < 0$. As such, $k = 2n$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and the solution is $$x = \pm \frac{\pi}{4} + 2n \pi,$$
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.